# Angular Client not setting Cookie with JSessionID

Tags: angular, spring, http, cookies, spring-security

I'm using an angular frontend, and a spring backend with spring security.
I have secured my API with the following code

```
            http
                    .cors().and()
//                    .csrf().disable()
                    .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
//                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/xrtool/*").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/advanced_search").hasRole("USER")
                        .antMatchers("/creation").hasRole("USER")
                        .antMatchers("/edit").hasRole("USER")
                        .antMatchers("/basicAuth").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .httpBasic();
```

I have no problems reaching the APIs with no protection (permitAll) but those which require a certain role give me a Status 401 unauthorized.
I believe that is due to my client not automatically setting the cookies after the initial authentication request.

The code for my authorization request:

```
  authenticate(username : string, password : string){

    let authHeader = new HttpHeaders({
      authorization : 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password),
      withCredentials: 'true'
    });

    return this.http.get(`${API_URL}/basicAuth`, {headers: authHeader})
  }
```

My backend code:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http
                    .cors().and()
                    .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/xrtool/*").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/advanced_search").hasRole("USER")
                        .antMatchers("/creation").hasRole("USER")
                        .antMatchers("/edit").hasRole("USER")
                        .antMatchers("/basicAuth").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .httpBasic();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

The response header for my initial request:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=475b11b6-39a4-4a46-a58d-e096a3bc07c6; Path=/
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=3E8382E29CB7C0AD9BBC168EA08ACF30; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 21 Jan 2023 17:56:43 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

And the subsequent request headers:

```
GET /xrtool/Test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
withCredentials: true
Origin: http://localhost:4200
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
```

The storage of the webclient also doesn't contain the Cookies.

I have tried it with different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge), but the result is consistent.

I tried accessing the APIs directly (localhost:8080/api/request) and everything is fine. I can also see the cookies in the webclient storage.

Postman also works fine. I can see the cookies being saved in the header, and after a initial authorization request, subsequent request are authorized.

I tried adding the authorization header in every request through an interceptor, and i was able to reach the APIs.

EDIT:

Thanks to Tr1Monsters' observation i was able to find the issue. The withCredentials header was at the wrong place. Appearently it doesn't need to be in the initial authentification request, but every subsequent request. I have added it to my Http-Intercept like this:

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let username = "b"
    let password = "b"
    let basicAuthHeaderString = "Basic " + window.btoa(username + ':' + password)

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        // Authorization: basicAuthHeaderString
      }
      , withCredentials: true
    })


    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

I have left in the original way i've added the header to show that the withCredentials header is placed outside the setHeaders part.

Comment: Some little sneaky thing got my attention. You set the withCredentials property as string and not as boolean. Just leave out the single quotes. Maybe this will wok. I'm not sure.

Comment: That was actually it! The withCredentials header was at the wrong spot.

Comment: Please add your solution as an Answer (it's totally legit to answer your own question btw.).
I initially missed it (didn't spend time reading question with no answers) and then spent hour, maybe two until i stumbled upon this thread again and miraculously caught an upvote on comment from Tr1monster.  

I did the same silly thing :D Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tr1Monsters' observation i was able to find the issue. The withCredentials header was at the wrong place. Appearently it doesn't need to be in the initial authentification request, but every subsequent request. I have added it to my Http-Interceptor like this:

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let username = "b"
    let password = "b"
    let basicAuthHeaderString = "Basic " + window.btoa(username + ':' + password)

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        // Authorization: basicAuthHeaderString
      }
      , withCredentials: true
    })


    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

I have left in the original way I've added the header, to show that the withCredentials header is placed outside the setHeaders part.